# How to fix an incorrect resolution setting without ADB

Tags: lineageos, android-tv, screen-resolution

I'm running Android TV on Lineage OS, on a Raspberry Pi 4. After changing the resolution setting, the connected display (a TV) no longer displays anything but the message "Video Format not supported".

How can I change the resolution setting back/reset it?

I have SSH enabled, but I don't know the default user/password for Lineage. USB debugging is disabled - otherwise I would have done this in ADB.

I've already done numerous searches on the Internet but can't find anything relevant. Will I just have to reflash and start again?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Connect to another display and set it back? Sounds like it's just your TV doesn't like it.

Comment: @AndyYan yea tried that... Problem is, the resolution is now set to 1080p@30, and I think it's the 30fps part that's breaking it.